# VS2010 build analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, build, buildconfiguration

I am working with a VS2010 solution we have inherited. It has approx 300 projects. Medium term I will try to break this down into multiple solutions, but I can't do that immediately.

One immediate problem is that if I do 2 consecutive builds, the second still does a lot of work, which says to me that something is wrong with the "make" configuration. What is the best way of analysing the build config to determine incorrect dependencies or other problems?

Is there a tool for doing this or shall I try and make my own?  Thanks.
(The solution was migrated through VS2005 and VS2008 before getting to VS2010 which probably didn't help the build config)

Answer (score 0):

The 'lot of work' from the second build could be just actions in the PreBuild steps, which are always executed. Make sure you get at least 'normal' instead of 'minimal' build output (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run). Just looking at the second output should give you the information you need. As far as I know there's no tool to compare to build log files, but it shouldn't be too hard to write it yourself.

Comment: Sebastiaan  Thank you - that's a good start, I can see over 1800 files (really) getting copied and several big projects rebuilding that I don't think should. Just got to figure out why!